# How to show an Audio Player on Alexa mobile App when playing an audio stream skill?

Tags: audio, alexa-skills-kit, mobile-application, audio-player

people.
I'm building a Radio Station app for Alexa Skill and I haven't figured out how to show an audio player inside the Alexa App when the skill is playing my audio stream.

For example, when playing the iHeart Radio skill, it shows an audio player bar in the bottom of the mobile app, which allows it to pause or change the volume. (check image below)

However, when playing my Radio, it just plays out the audio, but it doesn't show anything else.

I've been using the following projects as reference:
https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/blob/mainline/lambda/index.js
https://github.com/dabblelab/3-alexa-audio-streaming-example-skill/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js

[image]